# template functions c++ invalid initialization of non-const reference of type

Tags: c++, function-templates

in my FTemplate.h,

```
#ifndef FTemplate_h
#define FTemplate_h_h

template<typename T>
T& minus(const T& type1, const T& type2)
{
    return type1 - type2; // error here
}


#endif
```

in my main cpp

```
#include <FTemplate.h>
#include <Calculate.h>  
int main()
{
   Calculate cal;   
   Calculate cal1(42, 22);
   Calculate cal2(95, 48);
   cal difference = minus(cal1,cal2);

}
```

I am trying out function templates just to do a simple calculation but i met with this error :  `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Calculate &’ from an rvalue of type ‘Calculate ’` What have i done wrong here?

Comment: To understand the error, think of `return type1 - type2;` as something like this: `T& __function_result = type1 - type2; goto__end` (I'm not saying this is how C++ is implemented - just using it to illustrate what the error is telling you).
When you call `minus` from `main`, then it looks like this `Calculate& __function_result = type1 - type2;`
Now you should be able to see where there is an "initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Calculate &’" `__function_result` "from an rvalue of type ‘Calculate’" `type1 - type2`, This initialization is invalid as explained in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a reference to a temporary object created by `return type1 - type2 ;` in

```
T& minus(const T& type1, const T& type2)
~~~
```

Make it just `T minus(const T& type1, const T& type2)` for return by value.

`type1 - type2` results in rvalue which cannot bind to non const lvalue references.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the result `type1-type2` by reference. Which means you are taking a reference to a temporary object (technically `Calculate&&`) that will go out of scope. Try returning by value, i.e `T&` to `T`.